# page view titles not being shown

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview

the statements are being reached and the logs are printed but the views are not being changed at all. the text doesn't change for the textview and the visibility doesnt change for the 'bar' (a FrameLayout).

What could be the problem? Thanks guys.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == MyPageAdapter.DISCOVERY) {
                    findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar).setVisibility(1);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pullUpTitle)).setText("My Title 1");
                    Log.i("test","DICOVERY PAGE");
                } else 
                if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == MyPagerAdapter.EVENTS) {
                    findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar).setVisibility(1);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pullUpTitle)).setText("My Title 2");
                    Log.i("test","EVENTS PAGE");
                } else {
                    findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar).setVisibility(0);
                    Log.i("test","MAKE BAR NOT VISIBLE");
                }
            }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text not changing problem turned out to be that I was finding the view by ID in the listener. Actually it was causing a timeout and stopping the text from being updated.

So instead of using:

```
findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar).setVisibility(1);
```

I am now creating an instance in onCreate and using that (as shown below):

RelativeLayout rLayout;

```
onCreate(..){
...
rLayout = findViewById(R.id.pullupTitleBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Refer to blackbelt's answer to the second half of the question and dont forget to +1 him if you used his answer!

Thanks for the help guys :).

Answer (score 1):

use `View.VISIBLE` instead of pass the magic number `1` to `setVisibility` . The constant value is 0 for VISIBLE, 4 for `INVISIBLE` and 8 for `GONE`

Comment: this half answered my question thankyou! But for some reason the TextView text is not being updated still.

Comment: Ok I have solved the other half of the question and referenced you in the answer :). thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add mViewPager.notifyDataSetChanged() to the listener.